# iOS - loop through UIImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I have a couple of images which i have added to a `IBOutletCollection`:

`@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutletCollection(UIImageView) NSArray *walls;`

What I'm trying to is output the frame of each wall in the `NSArray` walls.

What i have tried:

```
for (UIImageView *wall in self.walls) {

    NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGRect(wall.frame));

}
```

but it just crashes giving me the error:`this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key wall.'`

Comment: This is not the code that is crashing. You have `[anObject valueForKey:@"wall"]` or similar somewhere else.

Comment: Or an IBOutlet link in one of your NIB files or storyboard scenes that points to a an outlet "wall" in your code, but you've since removed or renamed that IBOutlet from your code. That is the most common cause of this sort of error, and it can be maddening to try to find it.

Comment: @H2CO3 i don't have anything like that though. if i remove that `for loop`, it runs perfectly

Comment: @user3200111 A spelling error? Does the error message **really** say `wall` and not `walls`? All I can imagine is that it's really the `walls` key and a property that is declared but not synthesized.